# Ich würde etwas werden vs. ich würde etwas

Tags: subjunctive

Which one is correct?

I would like to become _____.

- Ich würde gern ________ werden.
- Ich würde gern ________ .

I was curious whether the sentences are grammatically correct, and if so, whether they are used in everyday German.

Comment: Hello! Please provide us with what you think is the right answer and why. Otherwise your question will likely be closed. Please be as precise as possible so we can help you more.

Comment: The question is clearly put. I don't see why language learners should always provide guesses and do not understand the close votes at all.

Comment: SE is for providing answers to questions of general interest. This looks like an exam question. At least it should be reworded so it becomes clear why it's of general interest. Also, the meaning of *werden* can be looked up in a dictionary. The question should tell why this didn't help.

Comment: It's a question about grammar, not meaning. If you are unable to recognise this, the fault might not be on the side of the person asking the question.

Comment: As it is worded, is it a question about the correct translation, not about grammar.

Comment: @Rha Silly me. I thought it was about the use of the subjunctive.

Comment: Both sentences are right, just not as given translation - and until now this question looks like translation, not grammar confusion. Into the first there fits nouns and adjectives, into the second there fits verbs. While `Ich wäre gern ...` also could be completed with nouns adjectives thus fullfilling the same approach like the first choice. There are just some more subtle differences in usage.

Comment: While the question looks like homework on the first glance, I consider it relevant and potentially interesting for future visitors due to the ambiguousness of werden (the question would of course benefit from more explicitly stating so); voted for re-open.

Comment: I think both means "I would be glad to become ...", but they use a different form of conditional. Probably native speakers can say, which one sounds better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both are correct, since *würde* can indicate the conjunctive (corresponding to first proposal) as well as mean *become* (2nd proposal).

The first variant nevertheless looks unattractive due to two derivations of *werden*.

So my first choice for translation is not listed:

> Ich möchte ___ werden.

Comment: But in real life nobody would say »Ich würde gern Lokführer.« (sounds like a pre-1900 novel that you had to read in high school ;-).